# Different orientations for multiple legends in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I produce a plot with two legends where one legend is vertical and the other legend is horizontal?

Using the iris data set, here is an example:

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Petal.Width,color=Species,size=Sepal.Length))+
geom_point() + 
scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(seq(from=5,to=7,by=0.4))) +
facet_wrap(~Species,ncol = 2) +
theme(legend.position=c(.7,.2))
```

I would like to have the `Species` color legend remain vertical but have the `Sepal.Length` legend be horizontal below it. Is this possible?

Note: I understand that the faceting makes the color legend unnecessary. I am simply using this as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the features of particular legends using the `guides` interface.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Petal.Width,color=Species,size=Sepal.Length))+
    geom_point() + 
    scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(seq(from=5,to=7,by=0.4))) +
    guides(size=guide_legend(direction='horizontal')) +
    facet_wrap(~Species,ncol = 2) +
    theme(legend.position=c(.7,.2))
```